# Saving images with Carrierwave inside a ruby worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, upload, carrierwave

I'm trying to write a method to store an image from a given url, inside a ruby worker. It comes along my Rails app in which I display the object image.
Here is what I've come up with :

```
def store(url)
    @object = Object.find(1)
    @object[:image] = CarrierWave::Uploader.store!(image_url)
end
```

It doesn't seem to work at all. 
Any clues?
Is there another way around?

[EDIT]

Here is the current situation :

```
def store
  @object = Object.find(1)
  my_uploader = ImageUploader.new

  image = open("http://twitpic.com/show/iphone/xxxx.jpg") 
# or for a local file:
  image = File.open(Rails.root.join('xxxx.png'))

  @object[:image] = my_uploader.store!(image)
  @object.save!
end
```

The filename in the [:image] attibute is still wrong. It gives "[:store_versions!]". How do I get the filename right?

[EDIT2]

Got the filename right by adding `@artwork[:image] = my_uploader.filename` before save.
But `@object = Object.find(1)` won't work. How do I access the Object class, which is inside my rails app, from the worker?

Comment: [EDIT] I've found out part of the solution: the image gets uploaded but the string in the @object[:image] is still wrong.

Comment: [EDIT2] Filename OK, still having trouble accessing the Object class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@object.image.store!(image)` finally did the job!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a new uploader object and point it to your file

```
image = File.open(Rails.root.join('path', 'to', 'file.png'))
@object[:image] = YourUploader.new(image)
```

Comment: how do you do this for a URL though, not a local file?

Comment: OK I'm trying this way. BTW this is for a local file isn't it? (and it lacks a closing parenthesis)

Comment: Yes, sorry, there should ebe an extra parenthesis :P If the file isn't available locally then you'll need to download it first, look at the ruby net http class. http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html